# How to make metric on each log that @Slf4j makes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, slf4j

I am using Lombook @Slf4j annotation for logging inside my project and now I want to expose metric with Prometheus on each log. For example how many error, info... logs there were. Any idea how to make that without rewriting every @Slf4j usage since there are many in the code.

Thought about using Aspects but not sure how and is there better solution.

Comment: Spring Boot already has a metric for that out-of-the-box.

Comment: Which one, how do I fetch it?

Comment: Can you please give some example on how to retrieve that metric or send documentation? thanks

Comment: That is just documented in the spring Boot documentation in observabitily. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.supported.logger for the loggers and they are available in the actuator endpoint under `/actuator/metrics`. You can even export them to your monitoring system of choice.